# Unable to start Django/Gunicorn via Supervisor

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm trying to start a Django project on a Debian server using Supervisor and Gunicorn.  When I run the command "sudo supervisorctl start gunicorn", I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/smith/venvs/hash1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/smith/venvs/hash1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/smith/venvs/hash1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/smith/venvs/hash1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/smith/venvs/hash1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/smith/venvs/hash1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/srv/http/example.com/repo/conf/wsgi.py", line 28, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/smith/venvs/hash1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/home/smith/venvs/hash1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/smith/venvs/hash1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/smith/venvs/hash1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/smith/venvs/hash1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/srv/http/example.com/repo/conf/settings/prod.py", line 2, in <module>
    from conf.settings.base import *
  File "/srv/http/example.com/repo/conf/settings/base.py", line 128, in <module>
    MEDIA_ROOT = get_env_variable('MEDIA_ROOT')
  File "/srv/http/example.com/repo/conf/settings/base.py", line 23, in get_env_variable
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
ImproperlyConfigured: Set the MEDIA_ROOT environment variable
[2016-01-27 19:39:31 +0000] [30408] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 30408)
```

My base.py base settings file reads environment variables which I set in my "hash1" virtual environment's postactivate hook:

```
# base.py
def get_env_variable(var_name):
    try:
        return os.environ[var_name]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the %s environment variable" % var_name
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
# The rest of my settings...
```

I've confirmed that the "ImproperlyConfigured" error message is being generated by this function in the settings file.

Here are my supervisor and gunicorn files:

```
# /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisor.conf
[program:gunicorn]
command=/srv/http/example.com/repo/bin/start-gunicorn
directory=/srv/http/example.com/repo
user=root
environment=MEDIA_ROOT="/var/www/swing/media/"

# start-gunicorn
#!/bin/bash
NAME=example
DJANGODIR=/srv/http/example.com/repo
USER=smith
GROUP=smith
WEBSITE=$NAME
NUM_WORKERS=3
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=conf.settings.prod
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=conf.wsgi

cd /home/smith/venvs/current/bin
source activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER \
  --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=127.0.0.1:8000 \
  --access-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/access.log \
  --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/error.log \
  --pid /var/tmp/gunicorn.pid \
  --log-level=info
```

I am using the default wsgi.py and supervisord.conf files.  My versions are as follows:

```
Django 1.8.4
Debian 8.2
Supervisor 3.0r1-1  (Installed globally)
Gunicorn 19.3.0     (Installed in virtual environment "hash1")
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  I wouldn't expect that supervisor could see my environment variables which is why I've set the MEDIA_ROOT variable via supervisor's "environment" parameter. But supervisor still doesn't seem to be seeing it.  I am able to start gunicorn when I run the start-gunicorn script from the command line.  I know I'm doing something stupid but I can't see it.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want to run your application as **root** user?

Comment: No, but at this point I'd just like to get it to run as *any* user.  If I can at least get it to run, then I could look at running it under my account.  This is always confusing to me, what accounts things should run under.  Nginx and Apache are pretty clear about running as www-data.  But gunicorn and supervisor?  With them, I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think the problem is that you are defining **MEDIA_ROOT** in the **root** user environment, then you run your program as **smith** user and it doesn't have **MEDIA_ROOT** defined in its environment.
Maybe you can try editing *base.py*

```
def get_env_variable(var_name):
    try:
        return os.environ[var_name]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the %s environment variable" % var_name
        # For debugging process append username and environment vars to error_msg
        user = os.environ['USER']
        env_vars = os.environ.keys()
        error_msg += " current user: %s env_vars: %s" % (user, env_vars)

        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
```

Then start django and check the error message to check if the user has **MEDIA_ROOT** defined in its environment.

Comment: The USER var wasn't present nor were any of the environment variables.  This is what I found: env_vars: ['LANG', 'VIRTUAL_ENV', 'SUPERVISOR_SERVER_URL', '_SYSTEMCTL_SKIP_REDIRECT', 'SHLVL', 'PYTHONPATH', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE', 'SUPERVISOR_ENABLED', 'SUPERVISOR_PROCESS_NAME', 'PWD', 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'SUPERVISOR_GROUP_NAME', 'PATH', 'PS1'].  I got same result when I replaced root with my account. When I hardcoded the e-vars in my settings, I *could* start gunicorn via supervisor. Since I'm switching to Ansible, I could just replace these e-vars with settings and vault the sensitive ones.